# Updating a bunch of Macs via SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, osx, sudo

allI'm working on a script that'll be running from our Mac server, and it will (hopefully) update all of our Macs via Munki (repo is on the same server) and the built-in `softwareupdate` command.

Here's my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
ADMIN_PASS='cat /Users/adminuser/Documents/Update\ Script/enPass.txt | base64 --decode'
ADMIN_USER="adminuser"
HOST_LIST="/Users/adminuser/Desktop/hosts.txt"

for HOST in $(< $HOST_LIST); do
  echo ""
  echo "--------------------------------"
  echo "# CONNECTING TO: $HOST #"
  echo "--------------------------------"
  echo ""

  ssh -tt $ADMIN_USER@$HOST sudo su << UPDATE
    echo "Connected to host!"
    /usr/local/munki/managedsoftwareupdate -v --auto

    softwareupdate -ia

    shutdown -r now

UPDATE

  echo ""
  echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
  echo "~~ Update script completed sucessfully on $HOST ~~"
  echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
  echo ""

done
```

I know I'm currently not using the ADMIN_PASS variable in this script. I dabbled with it in previous versions, and think that it's probably the way to go in terms of security (if you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears!).

Anyway, when I run this command as-is, it spits this back:

```
--------------------------------
# CONNECTING TO: 192.168.0.120 #
--------------------------------

    echo "Connected to host!"
    /usr/local/munki/managedsoftwareupdate -v --auto

    softwareupdate -ia

    shutdown -r now

Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
```

I'm assuming that the "Sorry, try again." is due to the `echo` command actually getting thrown into the Password prompt, but I'm unsure of the syntax to get this thing working properly with `sudo su` since the ADMIN_PASS variable is local and can't be passed to the ssh script without storing the file on the remote client (right?).

I need this script to run automatically without any input from admin, and I'd really like to avoid putting any part of it on the client systems.

Comment: Add `echo Made it past software Update` under `softwareupdater -ia` and add `echo made it past Shutdown` after `shutdown -r`  I believe we will never see Made it past shutdown, as the password is required for the shutdown command.  As a Simple fix move the shutdown command past the UPDATE SECTION, retest, and add Update Complete, Rebooting now.  If `shutdown` still fails, Calculate the average it takes for the script to complete, then multiply by the number of PC's.  Remove the `shutdown` from the script and schedule a cron job to reboot after all updates finish.

Comment: I've nixed the `shutdown` command entirely, and added `echo` in between each update command, but I'm still getting the "Sorry, try again" error. Looks like it's due to the `sudo su` command... will continue fiddling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Here is my functional script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ADMIN_PASS="$(cat /Users/adminuser/Documents/UpdateScript/enPass.txt)"
ADMIN_USER="adminuser"
HOST_LIST="/Users/adminuser/Desktop/hosts.txt"

for HOST in $(< $HOST_LIST); do
  echo ""
  echo "--------------------------------"
  echo "# CONNECTING TO: $HOST #"
  echo "--------------------------------"
  echo ""

  ssh -tt $ADMIN_USER@$HOST << ENDSSH

    echo 'Connected to host!'
    echo $ADMIN_PASS | base64 -d | sudo -S /usr/local/munki/managedsoftwareupdate -v --auto
    echo 'Finished Munki Update!'
    echo $ADMIN_PASS | base64 -d | sudo -S softwareupdate -ia
    echo 'Finished Apple Software Update!'
    echo $ADMIN_PASS | base64 -d | sudo -S shutdown -r now
    logout

ENDSSH


  echo ""
  echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
  echo "~~ Update script completed successfully on $HOST ~~"
  echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
  echo ""

done
```

Explicitly passing the `$ADMIN_PASS` variable to each command I wanted to run seems to work just fine. I had made an assumption that, because this was going to run on a remote Mac, the local `$ADMIN_PASS` variable wasn't going to work. I will continue messing with this, as I don't like the fact that it prominently displays the value in enPass.txt every time `echo $ADMIN_PASS` is used. Had hoped that this syntax would've sent it over to the `base64 -d` command and kept it off the Terminal window.

This functions well. If anyone has suggestions, let me know. I'm also curious of how secure this script is. If my brain is working properly, I *think* the encrypted password is being sent to the client system, and THEN is decrypted before being used in the `sudo -S` commands.